# Beginner SML Syntax

Tags: syntax, sml

I am very new to SML. I am currently working on a project that is checking to see if a mobile is balanced.

My datatype mobile is defined as follows:

```
datatype mobile = Object of int 
                | Wire   of mobile * mobile
```

Then I have a weight function to check the weight of a mobile:

```
fun weight (Object w)   = w 
  | weight (Wire (l,r)) = weight l + weight r
```

I am now trying to check if the mobile is balanced. I have the following:

```
fun balanced (Object w)   = true 
  | balanced (Wire (l,r)) = if weight l = weight r and balanced l and balanced r then true else false
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
stdIn:18.19-18.31 Error: syntax error: deleting  AND ID
stdIn:18.34 Error: syntax error found at AND
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As Brian points out, we use `andalso` and `orelse` in SML.

However there are no errors in the code, when this is fixed correctly.

Also as pointed out by Andreas Rossberg, when ever you write an expression of the form

```
if b then 
  true
else
  false
```

then you should immediately think of [this picture](http://static.quickmeme.com/media/social/qm.gif), and exchange it with the expression `b`, as it is obviously the same.

Given this, your `balanced` function end up looking something like this

```
fun balanced (Object w)   = true
  | balanced (Wire (l,r)) = weight l = weight r andalso
                            balanced l andalso balanced r
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way, this is a very inefficient way to determine whether a mobile
is balanced, because the weights of subtrees are computed over and over
again.  Think of a function weight_of_balanced_mobile that either returns
NONE if the mobile is not balanced or SOME w if it is balanced.

```
fun weight_of_balanced_mobile (Object w) = SOME w
  | weight_of_balanced_mobile (Wire (l,r)) =
       case weight_of_balanced_mobile l
         of NONE => NONE
          | SOME u => case weight_of_balanced_mobile r
                        of NONE => NONE
                         | SOME v => if u = v then SOME (u+v) else NONE;

 fun is_balanced mobile =
        case weight_of_balanced_mobile mobile
          of NONE => false
           | SOME _ => true;
```

The problem here is that your 'balanced' function returns just one bit of
information, whereas to compute efficiently, we need more information.  I
have come to regard Boolean as a danger sign.

Another way to structure the computation so that you get more information
(not just that something *is* balanced, but how heavy it is) is to pass
a continuation.  We'll make a function that takes a mobile and a 'what
to do if this mobile is balanced' argument.  Oh, let's make it take a
'value value to use if it isn't as well.

```
(* val check_balance : mobile -> 'a -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a *)
fun check_balance (Object w) _ f = f w
  | check_balance (Wire (l,r)) d f =
       check_balance l d (fn u =>
          check_balance r d (fn v =>
             if u = v then f (u+v) else d));

fun is_balanced mobile = check_balance mobile false (fn _ => true);
```

If you look at it just right, this is the same as the previous code
turned inside out.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `and` to `andalso` gets past the `syntax error found at AND` errors.

```
- fun balanced (Object w) =
    true | balanced(Wire(l,r)) = 
    if weight l = weight r andalso balanced l andalso r
    then
     true
    else
     false;
```

But then you get this:

```
stdIn:5.8-5.29 Error: operand of andalso is not of type bool [tycon mismatch]
  operand: mobile
  in expression:
    (balanced l) andalso r
```

which is because the type of the `weight` function is `val weight = fn : mobile -> int` which does not satisfy the boolean constraint for `andalso` since it returns an `int`.

Comment: In addition, `if b then true else false` is just a complicated way of saying `b`.