# Check if balanced binary tree (standard ml)

Tags: data-structures, tree, functional-programming, sml, ml

The tree datatype is :

```
datatype mobile = Object of int | Wire of mobile * mobile
```

To check if it's balanced I figured out I have to first make a weight function to calculate the weight of the values of each node and then compare left sub tree and right tree. However I have trouble putting this in ml language.

Code so far:

```
fun balanced  Object = true
if(weight(Wire(x,t1)) - weight(Wire(y,t1))) = 0)
   then true
else false
```

Comment: It is kind of sad, that you didn't even bothered to look for the answer, as one already exists here at SO :S. It must be getting close to hand in time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner SML Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365537/beginner-sml-syntax)